# 2005 Dodge Stratus car vibrates pressing on the brake

Tags: brakes, noise, suspension, dodge, brake-rotor

My car vibrates while holding the brake. While at a stop sign or a drive thru. Sometimes it's pretty loud and then sometimes it seems to stop. Putting it in neutral and park stops. It's only while pressing on the brake if I'm on a flat spot if I don't pressing my brake it doesn't make the sound. I noticed the sound after I had my brakes changed after about a week

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not quite following ... is it a sound or a vibration (or both)?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds exactly like the symptoms of a bad motor/transmission mount. With some help from another person this is easily confirmed. Here is a good video on how to identify failed motor mount on the transversely mounted engine and trans axle design which is used on a dodge stratus.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQqS6zie7ys

Comment: "Here is a good video" Can you summarize it to increase the value of your answer?

Comment: My answer has enough value as it is.

Comment: @L.hawes Some folks, like myself, do not have high-speed internet, and can not watch video with any reasonable efficiency.  By summarizing the video in one sentence, at least, you'd be greatly helping folks who depend on this largely text-only website for learning. I urge you to consider adding some content at your leisure. Please, and thank you in advance.

Comment: @L.hawes An answer that explains what the video shows is also superior because, here on the Stack Exchange sites, Comments are impermanent and sometimes or frequently disappear. Answer text remains, and is also searchable.